# Uploading video to dropbox using django app

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, dropbox

I need to upload video to dropbox using Django app.Please provide best way to upload.  I am using django form in order to take input from user.  Example will be better

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by going through dropbox core api itself.

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/python